# Scrolling with buttons

Tags: android, scroll

I am trying to scroll in a HorizontalScrollView using 2 buttons, one for left, one for right.
I cannot get a continous scroll, only on touch.
Can someone help?

Both cases work, but not continous:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.bRight:
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
sw.smoothScrollBy(20, 0);
}
break;
case R.id.bLeft:
sw.smoothScrollBy(-20, 0);
break;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRight:
            while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                sw.smoothScrollBy(20, 0);
                for(int i=0;i<10000;i++); //this only adds delay between scrolls, adjust as needed or remove
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.bLeft:
            while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                sw.smoothScrollBy(-20, 0);
                for(int i=0;i<10000;i++); //this only adds delay between scrolls, adjust as needed or remove
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you receive in LogCat?

Comment: ANR in app.android.joe /.Menu

Comment: Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

Comment: Try reducing the for loop to 500 or remove it completely and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, my guess is that you can only use polling not listeners, you need your onTouch listener to set a flag (global boolean variable) to true when ACTION_DOWN and false when ACTION_UP. You need to move the while loop to another thread that scrolls as long as the variable is true. Tell me if you need detailed code.

Comment: If i use ACTION_MOVE it moves continuous but i have to move my finger.